# Two DataReader from different classes but I get an error?

Tags: c#-4.0, ado.net

I have a project class, and related to it I have a categories class and responsible class. When I want to add a project object to database, I call a method from the categories class to get the categories id, and do the same for the responsible class. I mean:

```
int categoryId = getCategoryId("Beverages");
int responsibleId = getResponsibleId("An Example Name");
```

These two methods are in different classes, but use similar code. When I run the program I get the error:

```
"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."
```

Comment: You need to post more code, the reader you are using is either disposed of incorrectly or is not being disposed of at all.

Answer (score 0):

You must either fix your code, so that only one active (open) DataReader-object its active on a single DbConnection or enable MARS in your connection string (`MultipleActiveResultSets=True`).

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with Mithrandir here, but there is another workaround for your question; I suppose methods you listed access to the database (silly, I know , but bare it with me ), and they all open connection to same database. What you should add in your code is an final block,which closes database connection, after transaction is executed:

```
    try
          {
             string sql="select * from ...."
             connection.Open();
             comand.CommandText = sql;
             comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }

    catch(SQLException)
    {
    }

    finally
    {
     if (connection!=null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
    }
```